# Demonstrate complex number equality

Tags: complex-numbers

I am asked to develop this equality and demonstrate it, but I am stuck in the middle:

$$
(cos\theta + jsen\theta)^N  = cos(N\theta) + jsen(N\theta)
$$

Comment: Did you mean $(\cos \theta \color{red}{+}j\sin \theta)^N=\cos(N\theta)+j\sin(N\theta)$?

Comment: What did you try? where are you stuck?

Comment: I dunno how to advance at all.